# Is there anything wrong with this inequality proof?

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

Question: If $a<b$ and $a\cdot c <b\cdot c$ prove that $0<c$

Answer:

According to question $(bc-ac)$ is positive.

$(bc-ac)=(b-a)c$.

Implies $(b-a)c$ is positive.

Implies $(b-a)(c-0)$ is positive. [$c-0=c$]

$(c-0)$ is positive by closure under multiplication.

If $(c-0)$ is positive, $0<c$ by definition.

Comment: Nothing wrong, this is fine!! By closure under multiplication, you mean that $(b-a)$ is positive and hence so must be $c-0$?

Comment: @JimmyR. Thank you for the quick response. I am a bit confused as the book I got this question from says that "constructive methods used so far do not provide a proof." and then goes on to say that a proof by contradiction is needed.

The book has already provided use of the basic algebraic properties of a field of numbers, closure under addition and multiplication, and the trichotomy law. So I am a bit confused as to what it means that the proof can't be solved using constructive methods.

Comment: No, I think this is very nice like this. Only thing I do not know, what have you done so far. Perhaps you are not allowed to use that $(bc-ac)=(b-a)c$ but that would seem weird to me.

Comment: @JimmyR., Yes, that is what I mean by closure under multiplication.

And yes, I think the $(bc-ac)=(b-a)c$ might be what is not allowed, but I don't understand why that would be the case as it seems to follow from the properties I am allowed to use.

Comment: @JimmyR. Upon a further check, distributivity is a property I am allowed to use, so I don't know why the book says the proof can't be a constructive one.

Comment: Your "closure under multiplication" argument seems to say $x>0, xy > 0 \implies y> 0$.  You may need to justify that or its close cousin $x > 0 \implies \frac1x > 0$ without using a contradiction argument.

Comment: @Macavity The question implies $(b-a)c$ is positive. $(b-a)$ is positive according to the question. I do not understand where the problem is in using closure under multiplication here.

Comment: I should also add that "the product of two positive numbers is positive" is stated as a formal property of positive numbers in the start of the section.

Comment: @Macavity I think I see where the problem is. Is the use of the fact that only the product of two positives result in a positive the non-constructive part of the proof?

Comment: How does one prove $x>0, xy>0 \Rightarrow y>0$ constructively?